# How can I find element by text but it's number in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I want to get an element by text, but it is number? I guess?
For example,

```
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a>
```

It contain a number so this code didnt work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@text="11"]')
```

How can I find this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a web element(i.e div tag in this case) by its text content this way:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '11')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text,"11")]')
```

Please use above xpath to workout with this element

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element by it's text you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and `text()`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='11']")
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `contains()`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., '11')]")
  ```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ui-state-default' and text()='11']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ui-state-default' and contains(., '11')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```